# How to invoke /bin/login when starting Docker container

Tags: docker

I'm trying to start a Docker container that runs an application which relies heavily on `utmp` and `/bin/login`. In order for the application to work properly, it needs to read the logged in user via the `who` command (I can't change the app).

However when starting a new container, the usual login process doesn't happen, and `utmp` is never populated. As a result, commands like `who` never produce any output. This happens on all major images like Debian, Fedora, Alpine etc.

Is there any way to invoke `/bin/login` during container start up, feed it a username (created with a RUN command in the Dockerfile) and then have everything else execute in that shell?

I've tried combinations of `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` calling `/bin/login` (and tried `/bin/bash --login` but no luck. I can run `login` fine with an interactive shell once in the container, but I need it to start with the user logged in via `login`.

Using `USER` in the Dockerfile has no effect on `utmp`.

Edit: TL;DR is there a non-interactive way to login to a container using `/bin/login`?

Comment: Just so I'm sure I understand. The program sounds like it's meant to be run interactively, but you want to run it like a background process?

Comment: Run sshd, generate ssh key, add your own key as authorized_key, and login via ssh.

Comment: A virtual machine will have a more normal login environment and that might be a much easier way to run this particular process.

Comment: @HansKilian It's not interactive, does run as a background task, but does require the locally logged on user to be determined before it can start.

Comment: @KamilCuk this might be the best way, was hoping to avoid it though!